# gRPC timeout on server side

Tags: c++, timeout, grpc

I'm working on bidirectional stream gRPC in C++. I want to set a timeout limit on server side, and kill the connection if it exceeds a threshold.

But the only timeout mechanism I've found is on client side(https://grpc.io/blog/deadlines/#c). And I don't find any API possible to for ServerContext(https://grpc.github.io/grpc/cpp/classgrpc_1_1_server_context.html). Does someone know how to do that?

Comment: Do you want to kill active calls or are you looking to cancel for inactivity?

Comment: Cancel for inactivity

Answer (score 1):

gRPC does not support server side timeout limit/setting and hence you might need to have your own implementation mechanism and update client using context.abort.

Comment: Agree with you, I implemented my own timeout mechanism and cancel stream via ServerContext::TryCancel.

Comment: @Dentiny - I'd love to see your implementation as I have a similar issue.

Comment: @InsanityPants I just use a dummy method: (C++) https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_for

Comment: @Destiny - Yes, I came up with something very similar already. But thank you for taking the time to reply. Much appreciated.